# Merge two collections with different type parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism

I need to implement a class that basically holds a key and a value pair where the value is a sequence of  tuples. This tuple contains an object `SynthesizedMetricTag`, and a type parameter A with a `Numeric` context bound, so effectively a sequence of k/v where v needs to be a number.

```
case class Cohort[A : Numeric](index:Any,values:Seq[(SynthesizedMetricTag,A)])
```

The problem comes when I have to implement a function that merges two instances of this class. More specific, the problem comes when I have to merge a seq of type A with a seq of type B. Both types have a `Numeric` context bound, so the idea is that in the end I get a `Cohort[C]` that comforms to the context bound and merges all the K/V pairs of the sequences of type `A` and `B` without repeating any key.

```
case class Cohort[A : Numeric](index:Any,values:Seq[(SynthesizedMetricTag,A)]) {
  def merge[B : Numeric, C:Numeric](that:Cohort[B]):Cohort[C] =
    if(this.index != that.index) throw new Exception("Unable to merge Cohorts. Criteria is not the same")
    else {
      val b = new ArrayBuffer[(SynthesizedMetricTag,C)]()
      val seen = new mutable.HashSet[SynthesizedMetricTag]()
      for (x <- this.values; y <- that.values){
        if(!seen(x._1)){
          b+= x
          seen += x._1
        }
        if(!seen(y._1)){
          b+= y
          seen += y._1
        }
      }
      Cohort(this.index,b.toSeq)
    }
}
```

Of course this code throws the following errors:

```
[error] /Users/ernestrc/dev/everreach/operations-api/src/main/scala/everreach/operations/model/Cohort.scala:14: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (everreach.operations.model.SynthesizedMetricTag, A)
[error]  required: (everreach.operations.model.SynthesizedMetricTag, C)
[error]           b+= x
[error]               ^
[error] /Users/ernestrc/dev/everreach/operations-api/src/main/scala/everreach/operations/model/Cohort.scala:18: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (everreach.operations.model.SynthesizedMetricTag, B)
[error]  required: (everreach.operations.model.SynthesizedMetricTag, C)
[error]           b+= y
```

So I've tried the following:

```
case class Cohort[A : Numeric](index:Any,values:Seq[(SynthesizedMetricTag,A)]) {
  def merge[B : Numeric, C:Numeric](that:Cohort[B]):Cohort[C] =
    if(this.index != that.index) throw new Exception("Unable to merge Cohorts. Criteria is not the same")
    else {
      val b = new ArrayBuffer[(SynthesizedMetricTag,C)]()
      val seen = new mutable.HashSet[SynthesizedMetricTag]()
      for (x <- this.values; y <- that.values){
        if(!seen(x._1)){
          b+= x.asInstanceOf[(SynthesizedMetricTag,C)]
          seen += x._1
        }
        if(!seen(y._1)){
          b+= y.asInstanceOf[(SynthesizedMetricTag,C)]
          seen += y._1
        }
      }
      Cohort(this.index,b.toSeq)
    }
}
```

And it compiles, but I'm sure this is not the idiomatic way of doing this. Do you guys know how to solve this problem ?

**EDIT**

Alexey made a good point:

> What exactly do you want to happen if e.g. A is Double, B is Long, and
>   C is Byte?

Well `C` needs to be passed as a type parameter because otherwise the compiler doesn't know what `C` is, so I would like `A` and `B` to be converted to `C`. But what I really want to happen is to never lose information. So If for example, `A` is an `Int` and `B` is a `Float`, I want `A` to be converted to `Float` and merge both `A` and `B` into a collection `C`(`Float`).

Of course this hierarchy does not exist, does it? That's why I need to abstract the result type into `C` and manually pass it as a type parameter.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen if e.g. `A` is `Double`, `B` is `Long`, and `C` is `Byte`?

Comment: Well `C` needs to be passed as a type parameter because otherwise the compiler doesn't know what `C` is, so I would like `A` and `B` to be converted to `C`. 
But what i really want to happen is to never lose information. So If for example, `A` is an `Int` and `B` is a `Float`, I want `A` to be converted to `Float` and merge both `A` and `B` into a collection `C`(`Float`). 
Of course this hierarchy does not exist, does it? That's why I need to abstract the result type into C and manually determine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just define the method with an implicit evidence from types A and B to type C

```
case class Cohort[A <: Numeric](index:Any,values:Seq[(SynthesizedMetricTag,A)]) {
 def merge[B <: Numeric, C](that:Cohort[B])(implicit ev1:A=>C, ev2:B=>C):Cohort[C] =
   if(this.index != that.index) throw new Exception("Unable to merge Cohorts. Criteria is not the same")
   else {
     val b = new ArrayBuffer[(SynthesizedMetricTag,C)]()
     val seen = new mutable.HashSet[SynthesizedMetricTag]()
     for (x <- this.values; y <- that.values){
       if(!seen(x._1)){
         b += x._1 -> ev1(x._2)
         seen += x._1
       }
       if(!seen(y._1)){
         b+= y._1 -> ev2(y._2)
         seen += y._1
       }
     }
     Cohort(this.index,b.toSeq)
   }
}
```